# LVDS signals with vias around

Tags: via, lvds

I know it isn't best practice to put a via or a component in between LVDS traces. But my routing requires the LVDS traces to go in between of vias. How bad is this for the signal integrity?

[image]

Comment: Keep symmetry is my advice.

Comment: Assuming the LVDS traces are run in a stripline or microstrip configuration, you will probable never "see" the vias in your signal quality.  This type of routing is done all the time, especially when routing LVDS pairs through a connector or pin field.  As always for high speed designs, it's good advice to model what you're going to build, and build what you model.